# No one can hear me talking when I call people from my iPhone 5c unless I'm on speaker...

Tags: microphone, iphone

How do I fix this? It was fine up until a couple of days ago and everything was working. Should I bring it into an Apple store?

Answer (score 2):

This happens frequently to me, but turns out my phone is simply connected to a bluetooth device that I *thought* was turned off. Try turning off bluetooth just to eliminate this as an issue.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203792) has this to say:

> **Fix common issues**
>
> Follow these steps, testing after each with Voice Memos.
>
> 1. Unplug anything plugged into the headset jack.
> 2. If you're on a call and holding your phone next to your ear, speak into the microphone and make sure you don't block it with your fingers
>      or shoulder.
> 3. If you're using a screen protector or case that covers the microphone, remove it. **Clear any debris from the microphones.**
> 4. Restart your device.
> 5. Update to the latest version of iOS.

The mic used for normal calls is the bottom one, check for debris and remove it carefully. There is a membrane between the mic and the phone internals, be careful not to puncture it.

[image: iPhone 5c bottom mic]

Couldn't find a better pic, sorry.

There are two more microphones, one beside the camera on the back and other near the speaker on top iPhone the phone, they are used for videos and noise canceling; clean them carefully too.

Comment: thanks! i'll try that when i get home... is there anything in particular that i should clean it with? or just a microfiber cloth?

Comment: @Lauren try a needle or something small enough to remove whatever may be lodged on the small whole, be careful with the membrane (although on the iPhone 6 it seems to be a little metallic grill, it's not *that* fragile)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes simply restarting the iPhone solves most of the problem.

1. Press and Hold Power + Home button for few seconds until you see Apple logo rebooting.

This works in my case, most of the time. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is the memory full? My mother in law had the same problem with her iPhone 6. WhatsApp was auto saving every photo and meme sent to her to Photos and it filled the phone memory. Freeing space actually resolved the issue.